# How to convert numpy array to bytes object without save audio file on disk?

Tags: python, arrays, audio, mp3, wav

I am now learning to build a TTS project based on Tacotron-2.

[Here](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2/blob/master/datasets/audio.py), the original code in `save_wav(wav, path, sr)` function has a step to save a numpy array to .wav file by using

```
wav *= 32767 / max(0.01, np.max(np.abs(wav)))
scipy.io.wavfile.write(path, hparams.sample_rate, wav.astype(np.int16))
```

However, after obtained a numpy array using `wav *= 32767 / max(0.01, np.max(np.abs(wav)))`, I want to convert it to a .mp3 file so that it will be easier to send it back as streaming response.

Right now, I can convert .wav bytes object to a .mp3 file, but the problem is that I don't know **how to convert the numpy array to a .wav bytes object**.

I searched about it and found that it seems like I need to set a header for the numpy array, but in almost all posts that I looked into indicated using modules like `scipy.io.wave` and `audioop`, which will first save the numpy array to a .wav file and then `with open('filename.wav', 'rb')`.

(This is the [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) for scipy.io.wavfile.write module, where the `filename` param should be *string or open file handle* which, from my understanding, the generated .wav file will be saved on disk.)

Could anyone give any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

### Use `io.BytesIO`

There is a much simpler and more convenient solution using a little hack creating i/o interface of bytes. We can use it like file for `write` and `read`:

```py
import io
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

bytes_wav = bytes()
byte_io = io.BytesIO(bytes_wav)
write(byte_io, <audio_sr>, <audio_numpy_array>)
result_bytes = byte_io.read()
```

Use your data sample rate and values array instead of `<audio_sr>` and `<audio_numpy_array>`.
You can operate with `result_bytes` as bytes of **.wav** file (as required).

P.S. Also check [this simple gist](https://gist.github.com/hadware/8882b980907901426266cb07bfbfcd20) of how to perform `values array -> bytes -> values array` for wav file.

Comment: Just an fyi, if using similar methods and `byte_io.read()` returns nothing then you might need to seek to the beginning of the file with `byte_io.seek(0)` before reading.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by modifying and creating new modules based on **scipy.io.wavfile.write** and **audio_segment.py** of **[pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)**.

Beside, when you want to do operation on wave/mp3 bytes without saving them as a .wav/.mp3 file (normally by using some handful APIs or python package module), you should manually add header for it. It will not be a too-tough task if you look into those excellent package source codes.

Comment: Are you able to provide the solution you mentioned? Some Wav files may have a non-standard header for example which makes this harder.